# Identifying the type of conic using its symmetric matrix in the extended Euclidean plane

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

I have represented the conic $C$ in the Euclidean plane described by the equation
$$3x^{2}+ 2y^{2}+ 7xy + 4x + 5y + 3 = 0$$ as a symmetric matrix. \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 7/2 & 2\\ 7/2 & 2 & 5/2\\ 2 & 5/2 & 3\end{pmatrix}.

Now I am asked to show that $C$ is nonsingular and identify the type of conic.  I think I have shown it is nonsingular using the fact that $A$ is singular, i.e the determinant of $A$ is $0$ if and only if the polynomial $X^{t}AX$ can be factorized over the complex numbers into two linear factors. I did this by calculating $X^{t}AX$ to obtain $17/2x^{2}+8y^{2} +15z^{2}$ and stated that this cannot be factorized thus it is non singular.

I need help with identifying the type of conic.  I initially took the result from above, $17/2x^{2}+8y^{2} +15z^{2}$ and converted it back into Cartesian but could not get it in the form of any conic. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Let the matrix you have described be called by $A_Q$ and $Q$ be the type of conic.

If $\det A_Q =0$, then the conic is degenerate. If $\det A_Q\neq 0$, so that the conic is not degenerate, we can see what type of conic it is by computing the minor, $\det A_{33}$. Thus,
$(1)$ It is a hyperbola iff $\det A_{33}<0$.
$(2)$ It is a parabola iff $\det A_{33} =0$.
$(3)$ It is an ellipse iff $\det A_{33} >0$.

In your case, we have $\det A_{33} = 3\times 2-(\frac{7}{2})^{2} < 0$. So it is a **hyperbola**. Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't quite understand, what is the minor det?

Comment: I forgot to add a comma. My edit would have made it clear, I think?

Comment: Sorry this may seem silly but I can't quite see what the difference is between $A_{Q}$ and $A_{33}$

Comment: Let the conic Q(x,y) be represented in the form of that matrix you have with you. So,$A_Q$ is its determinant. $A_{ij}$ for a matrix A is called its minor. You can see about it [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra)).

Comment: Why does it have to be for $A_{33}$?

Comment: The minor $A_{23}$ gives me a different answer

Comment: That is the definition for determining the type of conic. No other way I know of.

Comment: Ah so just to clarify, to determine the type of conic, one must always pick $A_{33}$?

Comment: Yes, @harry55. No other minor is allowed. Hope it helps.